# does anyone has an example using $httpBackend (service in module ngMockE2E )

Tags: mocking, angularjs

I'm really looking to find the simplest way to get my angular app to use a mock backend service.

any pointers would be great, a sample app that show how to write a simple app the use it would do the job. tnx!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is a [sample plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/QYKAKvqO9OX8n9uuBSGx?p=preview) using the $httpBackend for a sample with backend-less development as an example to answer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14973602/how-to-access-nested-objects-in-json-by-angularjs-resource).

The main things I added to the plnkr to get this to work are:

1. Referenced the `angular-mocks.js` file in the html.
2. Added `ngMockE2E` in the angular.module requires array on line 3 in app.js
3. Injected `$httpBackend` to the app.run and added code to tell the mock backend what to respond with when a GET to a specific URL is requested.

This was mostly taken from the [$httpBackend](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMockE2E.$httpBackend) documentation. Note you can do a `.passThrough()` for any calls where you want to actually hit the backend (bypassing the mock). This is especially useful if portions of the backend are already working.

Comment: '.passThrough()' will be also useful for loading templates otherwise '$httpBackend' interferes the usual template loading mechanism.  For example mention,

'$httpBackend.whenGET(/\.html$/).passThrough();'

Answer (score 2):

Here is a basic template pulled from various examples:

```
'use strict';

(function() {

    if( !document.URL.match(/\?nobackend$/) ){
        // if not requested only add a blank stub to app dependency.
        angular.module('ds.backendMock', []);

    } else if (document.URL.match(/\?nobackend$/)) {

        // if the query string is present add a module with a run definition to replace the back end.
        angular.module('myMock', ['ngMockE2E'])

            .run(function($httpBackend) {

                // MOCK-RUNNER-CONFIGURATION-.
                var DOMAIN = 'example.com',
        $httpBackend.whenGET('http://'+DOMAIN+'/someexample')
                    .respond(
                        //MOCK-ERROR-STATUS-CODE
                        //401 //500 //404  //uncomment integer to mock status code and comment out mock data.
                        //MOCK-DATA-RESPONSE
                        {
                          'id' : '1',
                          'name' : 'MOCK',
                          'description' : 'mocking',

                        }
                    ); //end mock.


                    // various passthroughs. these allow existing services to work, while some are mocked.
                    $httpBackend.whenGET('./some.html').passThrough();

                    // dont mock everything else, specify pass through to avoid error.
                    $httpBackend.whenGET(/^\w+.*/).passThrough();
                    $httpBackend.whenPOST(/^\w+.*/).passThrough();

                });

        }

})(angular);
```