# How to access nested objects in json by angularjs $resource

Tags: json, rest, angularjs, nested

I have .NET WCF service providing REST service. Everything works for me, until I am trying to send object with nested objects. Then I am getting nothing in angularjs. How can I use/access nested object for data exchange?

.NET service part:

```
[OperationContract] // route prefix 'api'
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "users/{id}/privileges", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    public PrivilegeSet GetPrivileges(string id)
    {
        var response = new PrivilegeSet();

        List<Role> roles = new List<Role>();
        roles.Add(new Role() { RoleId = 1, Name = "Role 1", Active = true });
        roles.Add(new Role() { RoleId = 2, Name = "Role 2", Active = true });
        roles.Add(new Role() { RoleId = 3, Name = "Role 3", Active = false });
        response.Roles = roles;

        List<SubRole> subRoles = new List<SubRole>();
        subRoles.Add(new SubRole() { SubRoleId = 1, Name = "SubRole 1", RoleId = 1, Active = true });
        subRoles.Add(new SubRole() { SubRoleId = 2, Name = "SubRole 2", RoleId = 1, Active = true });
        subRoles.Add(new SubRole() { SubRoleId = 3, Name = "SubRole 3", RoleId = 1, Active = false });
        response.SubRoles = subRoles;

        return response;
    }
```

JSON structure:

```
{
"Roles": [
{
  "Active": true,
  "Name": "Role 1",
  "RoleId": 1
},
{
  "Active": true,
  "Name": "Role 2",
  "RoleId": 2
},
{
  "Active": false,
  "Name": "Role 3",
  "RoleId": 3
}
],
"SubRoles": [
{
  "Active": true,
  "Name": "SubRole 1",
  "RoleId": 1,
  "SubRoleId": 1
},
{
  "Active": true,
  "Name": "SubRole 2",
  "RoleId": 1,
  "SubRoleId": 2
},
{
  "Active": false,
  "Name": "SubRole 3",
  "RoleId": 1,
  "SubRoleId": 3
}
]
}
```

Angularjs service:

```
angular.module('privilegeService', ['ngResource']).
    factory('Privilege', function ($resource) {
        return $resource('api/users/:userId/privileges', {userId: '@id'});
    });
```

Angularjs fetching part:

```
function PrivilegesCtrl($scope, Privilege) {
    $scope.privileges = Privilege.query({userId:2}); // privileges remains empty using nested objects, with one level object works fine
    ...
```

Why privileges remains empty when JSON has nested objects? And how to access nested objects in the view?

Comment: Have you checked in any dev tools like Firebug or Chrome Inspector for what the server is returning?

Comment: Of course, it is the JSON structure part. It it is the server response.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you use the [$resource](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.%24resource) service the `.query` action assumes your response is an array. You can specify that the response is not an array when using `.query` by specifying it when creating the resource with the third parameter below:

```
angular.module('privilegeService', ['ngResource']).
    factory('Privilege', function ($resource) {
        return $resource('api/users/:userId/privileges', 
                         {userId: '@id'}, 
                         {'query':  {method:'GET', isArray:false}});
    });
```

Check out [this plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/QYKAKvqO9OX8n9uuBSGx?p=preview) for an example. If you take out the `{'query':  {method:'GET', isArray:false}}` your response will be an empty array.

**Note 1:** your console is likely showing an error `TypeError: Object #<Resource> has no method 'push'` which, when working with `.query`, usually means an array is expected from your REST call.

**Note 2:** the resource action defaults are described in the [$resource](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.%24resource) documentation as follows:

```
{ 'get':    {method:'GET'},
  'save':   {method:'POST'},
  'query':  {method:'GET', isArray:true},
  'remove': {method:'DELETE'},
  'delete': {method:'DELETE'} };
```

Comment: It works, thank you. How can I now access nested arrays in the view?

Comment: The resource returns an object with two arrays in it called `Roles` and `SubRoles`. You can reference them using `privileges.Roles` and `privileges.SubRoles` respectively. I updated the plnkr with an example.

Comment: I was trying it by this way, but it needs deeper browser refresh after changes. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @Gloopy Why can't i go `privileger.Roles[0].$delete` when `isArray:false` is there anyway that is achievable

Comment: @Deeptechtons ngResource converts your array to Resource objects when `isArray: true` (and assumes the objects are the same `Privilege` resource in this case). Also in this example you might want a resource for a Role and SubRole since they presumably would have their own endpoints to delete them. Then you would need to create or use the Role/SubRole resource to do `.delete` or `.$delete` check out [this](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.$resource) for more info. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Gloopy is there a way i can convert it to Resource so i can call `obj.$delete` instead of declaring resource for the same and doing `injFactory.Resource.Delete(obj)`

Comment: @Deeptechtons you can convert it to the resource using `new Resource(obj)` where Resource is your $resource (like Role or SubRole). See [line 27](http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.3/docs/api/ngResource.$resource#example) in the $resource documentation for an example.